# ASP.NET Static File Delivery vs ASHX Handler Response.WriteFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm tempted to use an `.ASHX` for image delivery to have pretty Urls *(totally legit reason)* and monitor access and such. I have other reasons but... I could live with static delivery also.

**I'm interested to learn what's the performance penalty of dynamic delivery compared to plain-old static file delivery from someone who's already done it.**

I've read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2008/05/02/asp-net-performance-sin-serving-images-dynamically-or-another-reason-to-love-fiddler.aspx) and I'll issue caching headers properly to ensure client side caching.

Aside from this gotcha, how do the two methods stack against each other and should I just stick to static delivery?

**PS**: *I'm new to ASP.NET so I'm trying to tap into the experience of someone who has already done this. Trying not to learn it the hard way. :)*

Comment: **Too broad? It's actually very specific!** Performance comparison between shipping binary data directly or through a handler. No extra anything happening. Can it get more specific than this? I know how it is in PHP and it's very bad there. But given the way ASP.NET and IIS work together... things might be more acceptable.

Comment: The biggest problem with serving static content dynamically is that it's going to allocate much more overhead since it is initializing a full ASP.NET request for each file (although an ashx is lighter than a web form or mvc route). We had some major problems with serving a lot of static files in a short time when using handles instead of IIS. This was years back though (IIS6 even I think), so handlers may have gotten better. My best advice is to set up a test where you get a lot of static files using both methods and compare memory use, CPU, thread count etc.

Comment: @AndersBornholm I think this is what I'm gonna do. Problem is I don't have any way to do this naturally. So I'll need to set up multiple cloud instances to hammer a cloud server so I don't bottleneck on the client. Thought I could avoid this by tapping into the collective knowledge. :)

Comment: To start with you could probably get a long way with just two local machines, I think you'll see trends pretty clearly